# How to concatenate simple-arrays and keep the element-type '(unsigned-bytes 8) in Common Lisp?

Tags: arrays, lisp, concatenation, common-lisp

I got two simple-arrays, of which element-type is '(unsigned-byte 8). If I use `(concatenate 'vector array-A array-B)`, the result array's element-type won't be '(unsigned-byte 8) anymore.

How can I concatenate arrays and keep their element-type in Lisp?

Comment: how about telling Lisp that you actually want a `(vector (unsigned-byte 8))` instead of a `vector`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Rainer Joswig points out in the comments, you could simply specify the element type of your result vector:

```
(concatenate '(vector (unsigned-byte 8)) array-A array-B)
```

Note that the [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_concat.htm) says:

> If the *result-type* is a subtype of vector, then if the implementation
>   can determine the element type specified for the *result-type*, the
>   element type of the resulting array is the result of *upgrading* that
>   element type.

Therefore, your LISP implementation is free to choose a "better" element type for the result vector (this might happen if you specify something like `(unsigned-byte 5)`, for instance).

Answer (score 6):

You might try doing something like this to return an array of the same type as the first array:

```
(concatenate (type-of array-A) array-A array-B)
```

Unfortunately, this won't work very well because the type may include the length of the array, and you probably want a longer array.

If you're willing to lose a little generality, you can go with:

```
(concatenate `(vector ,(array-element-type array-A)) array-A array-B)
```

This will return a vector with the same element type as `array-A`, whatever that may be.